# Check specific character in Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

How check if a String contains only one specific character?
Eg:

On the String `square/retrofit` and `square/retrofit/issues` I need to check if the String has more than one `/` character.

`square/retrofit/issues` need to be false because have more than one `/` character and `square/retrofit` need to be true.

The string can have numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need regex. Simple `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` methods should be enough.

```
boolean onlyOne = s.indexOf('/') == s.lastIndexOf('/');
```

EDIT 1
Of course, if `/` does not appear in given string above will be `true`. So, to avoid this situation you can also check what is returned index from one of these methods.

EDIT 2
Working solution:

```
class Strings {
    public static boolean availableOnlyOnce(String source, char c) {
        if (source == null || source.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        int indexOf = source.indexOf(c);
        return (indexOf == source.lastIndexOf(c)) && indexOf != -1;
    }
}
```

Test cases:

```
System.out.println(Strings.availableOnlyOnce("path", '/'));
System.out.println(Strings.availableOnlyOnce("path/path1", '/'));
System.out.println(Strings.availableOnlyOnce("path/path1/path2", '/'));
```

Prints:

```
false
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you'd like to use a bit more modern approach with streams:

```
boolean occursOnlyOnce(String stringToCheck, char charToMatch) {
    return stringToCheck.chars().filter(ch -> ch == charToMatch).count() == 1;
}
```

Disclaimer: This is not supposed to be the most optimal approach.

A bit more optimized approach:

```
    boolean occursOnlyOnce(String stringToCheck, char charToMatch) {
    boolean isFound = false;
    for (char ch : stringToCheck.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch == charToMatch) {
            if (!isFound) {
                isFound = true;
            } else {
                return false; // More than once, return immediately
            }
        }
    }
    return isFound; // Not found
}
```